# color list view

Tags: android, listview, colors

I'm trying to insert data into listview. my list view is made from 3 columns and I want to compare the data (grades) in the listview to a number. If it's bigger I want the color of the  row to be green and if it's smaller it will be colored in red.

So basiclly I want the list view to change colors- every row in another color? by a specific law.

Thanks for the help,
Marina

Answer (score 1):

On your `getView()` method of your adapter you can compare the numbers and change the backgroud color according to what you want. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781849/change-background-color-of-first-item-in-listview?rq=1) link.